# How to Remove/Hide the "Delete" function inside the "More" button in State "Done" Odoo

Tags: xml, security, odoo-12

I'm currently using Odoo 12 and I want to remove the 'Remove' function from the 'More' button in the back-end for all groups in state 'done'

I tried with this code but I do not know where I add the *state*

```
  <record id="view_tree_mymodule_hide_delete" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">my.module</field>
    <field name="model">my.module</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="my.module.my_module_tree"/> 
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <xpath expr="//tree" position="attributes">

        <attribute name="delete">false</attribute>

        </xpath>

    </field>
</record>
```

the code works but for all state
I just want in the state "DONE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find solution but not to hide the delete, with method **unlink** python

```
@api.multi
def unlink(self):
    for order in self:
        if order.state not in ('draft'):
            raise UserError(_('Deleting is only possible in case of draft'))
    return super(NameClass, self).unlink()
```